# How to get your content type in the new document fly-out

Tags: 2013, content-type, document-template

In a document library, when pushing the plus button you get te flyoutmenu wth all the office doc types. Any simple way of getting your own content types into this fly-out? It looks like as soon as flick the switch to manage content types, this menu disappears.

Any hints?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the 'new document' link just above the list of items, it will open a fly-out that includes the 4 typical Office documents (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, OneNote) as well as a folder and 'upload' option.

I believe the OP wants to also include custom types in this fly-out as well. However, it doesn't seem possible without adding your own custom JS script to create a custom fly-out.

> The answer given by @WantToDodoesn't answer the OP question. The fly-out
>   the OP is referring to is from a default Document Library without
>   'Allow management of content types' enabled.

Comment: this is a statement, more properly placed with the answer it is replying too.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring too are called "Call Outs", and they have their own API and is loaded from callout.js.  These are done separately from content types, but you could create a solution that checks for a specific content type and activates them if present.

Example of using the callouts (you could load this on a script part on the page to test).

```
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CreateCallOutPopup, "callout.js");


    //get our launchpoint - where callout will appear
    var targetElement = document.getElementById('QCB1_Button1');

    // check for current callout
    var currentCallOut = CalloutManager.getFromLaunchPointIfExists(targetElement);

    /remove it if exists    
    if(!currentCallOut){
        CalloutManager.remove(targetElement);
    }

    //Configure new Callout
    var calloutOptions = new CalloutOptions();

    calloutOptions.ID = 'MyCustomCallOut';
    calloutOptions.launchPoint = targetElement;
    calloutOptions.beakOrientation = 'leftRight';
    calloutOptions.content = ' My Content';
    calloutOptions.title = 'My Title';

    //Create the callout
    var myCallOut = CalloutManager.createNew(calloutOptions);

    //Create custom action for callout
    var myAction = new CalloutActionOptions();
    myAction.text = 'My Special Action';
    myAction.onClickCallback = function(event, action)
    {
        alert("I can do whatever you want");
    };

    var newAction = new CalloutAction(myAction);

    //Add the action to the callout
    myCallOut.addAction(newAction);
```

Answer (score -1):

to manage content types:

1. in Library Settings --> Advanced settings --> allow to manage content types
2. add content types

I don't know if it help you because it's same upload document in top menu
after upload document you can choose the content type (edit properties Opens immediately you select the file to upload)

[image: uploads]

but, all content types are alloed, Displayed on menu on top files--> new document

[image: contentTypes]

Comment: The question is not about ribbon menu, where content types are showed.